leftmost card in the automatic card slider is not completely displayed
I integrated this automatic slider card html code on my site, but the entire leftmost card does not display and looks like it is cut off.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
  const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel");
  const firstCardWidth = carousel.querySelector(".card").offsetWidth;
  const arrowBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper i");
  const carouselChildren = [...carousel.children];

  let isDragging = false,
    isAutoPlay = true,
    startX, startScrollLeft, timeoutId;

  let cardPerView = 10;

  carouselChildren.slice(-cardPerView).reverse().forEach(card => {
    carousel.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", card.outerHTML);
  });

  carouselChildren.slice(0, cardPerView).forEach(card => {
    carousel.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", card.outerHTML);
  });

  carousel.classList.add("no-transition");
  carousel.scrollLeft = carousel.offsetWidth - wrapper.offsetWidth + (firstCardWidth * cardPerView) / 2;
  carousel.classList.remove("no-transition");

  arrowBtns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      carousel.scrollLeft += btn.id === "left" ? -firstCardWidth : firstCardWidth;
    });
  });

  const dragStart = (e) => {
    isDragging = true;
    carousel.classList.add("dragging");
    startX = e.pageX;
    startScrollLeft = carousel.scrollLeft;
  };

  const dragging = (e) => {
    if (!isDragging) return;
    carousel.scrollLeft = startScrollLeft - (e.pageX - startX);
  };

  const dragStop = () => {
    isDragging = false;
    carousel.classList.remove("dragging");
  };

  const infiniteScroll = () => {
    if (carousel.scrollLeft === 0) {
      carousel.classList.add("no-transition");
      carousel.scrollLeft = carousel.scrollWidth - (2 * carousel.offsetWidth);
      carousel.classList.remove("no-transition");
    } else if (Math.ceil(carousel.scrollLeft) === carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.offsetWidth) {
      carousel.classList.add("no-transition");
      carousel.scrollLeft = carousel.offsetWidth;
      carousel.classList.remove("no-transition");
    }

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    if (!wrapper.matches(":hover")) autoPlay();
  };

  const autoPlay = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 800 || !isAutoPlay) return;
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => carousel.scrollLeft += firstCardWidth, 1000);
  };

  autoPlay();

  carousel.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
  carousel.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragStop);
  carousel.addEventListener("scroll", infiniteScroll);
  wrapper.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => clearTimeout(timeoutId));
  wrapper.addEventListener("mouseleave", autoPlay);
});
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Wix+Madefor+Text:ital,wght@0,400..800;1,400..800&display=swap');

* {
  0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  'Poppins',
  sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  0 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1560px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #E21C21;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrapper i#left {
  left: 10px;
}

.wrapper i#right {
  right: 10px;
}

.wrapper i:hover {
  color: #020202;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 15px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.carousel.no-transition {
  scroll-behavior: auto;
}

.card {
  min-width: 130px;
  max-width: 130px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.3);
}

.card .img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.card .text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  10px;
  "Wix Madefor Text",
  sans-serif;
}
<!-- Fontawesome Link for Icons -->
<link rel="nofollow" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css">
<!-- Google Fonts Link -->
<link rel="nofollow" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="nofollow" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="nofollow" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Wix+Madefor+Text:ital,wght@0,400..800;1,400..800&amp;display=swap">
<div class="wrapper">
  <i id="left" class="bx bx-chevron-left" aria-label="Scroll Left"></i>
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <a href="https://www.porsche.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/u0tKzKe.png" alt="Porsche Logo" draggable="false"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Porsche</div>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <a href="https://www.fiat.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EZ0DQqx.png" alt="Fiat Logo" draggable="false"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Fiat</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <i id="right" class="bx bx-chevron-right" aria-label="Scroll Right"></i>
</div>



I can't share the full code but here it is:
https://justpaste.it/f8u82

how can I fix this

thank you, as you will see when you run it, the entire leftmost card is not displayed

As you can see in these simplified examples, the issue is caused by your scroll-snap-align setting.

In both strips I have added 30px of left and right padding
In the top strip I have used scroll-snap-align: center
In the bottom strip I have used scroll-snap-align: start

As you can see, when scrolling the bottom strip sideways, the cards want to snap to the left side of the container. The container has 30px of left padding to the left of the first card, but it's difficult to scroll to it. In Safari, if I scroll left from the first card and pause while continuing to hold down the mouse button, it will show this padding to the left of the card. Then after a few seconds it will snap back so that the edge of the first card is aligned with the left edge of the container.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Nqr3VqpW8k
I think your best option is just to snap to the centre rather than the start.


body {
  background: #888;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px 30px 25px;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  margin: 0 0 2em;
  background: white;
  border-top: 5px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
}

.card {
  min-width: 130px;
  max-width: 130px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.c2 .card {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.3);
}

.card .img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.card .text {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
}
<ul class="carousel">
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.porsche.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/u0tKzKe.png" alt="Porsche Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Porsche</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.fiat.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EZ0DQqx.png" alt="Fiat Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Fiat</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.porsche.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/u0tKzKe.png" alt="Porsche Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Porsche</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.fiat.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EZ0DQqx.png" alt="Fiat Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Fiat</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.porsche.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/u0tKzKe.png" alt="Porsche Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Porsche</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.fiat.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EZ0DQqx.png" alt="Fiat Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Fiat</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.porsche.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/u0tKzKe.png" alt="Porsche Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Porsche</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.fiat.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EZ0DQqx.png" alt="Fiat Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Fiat</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="carousel c2">
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.porsche.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/u0tKzKe.png" alt="Porsche Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Porsche</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.fiat.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EZ0DQqx.png" alt="Fiat Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Fiat</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.porsche.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/u0tKzKe.png" alt="Porsche Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Porsche</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.fiat.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EZ0DQqx.png" alt="Fiat Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Fiat</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.porsche.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/u0tKzKe.png" alt="Porsche Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Porsche</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.fiat.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EZ0DQqx.png" alt="Fiat Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Fiat</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.porsche.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/u0tKzKe.png" alt="Porsche Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Porsche</div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="https://www.fiat.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EZ0DQqx.png" alt="Fiat Logo" draggable="false"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Fiat</div>
  </li>
</ul>



